# OIDC Token Refresh with no IFrame in a Reactjs App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oidc-client-js, oidc-client-ts

I am currently developing a ReactJS application and using OIDC-Client-TS for implementing an Authorization Flow. While the current setup functions adequately, I've encountered a challenge during token refresh operations. The 'signinSilent' method is ineffective due to the blocking of iframes within my company browser environment and hence I am currently unable to silently refresh a token.

Although the 'signinPopup' method remains an option for token refresh, my preference leans toward achieving silent renewal without relying on iframes.

Would anyone know of another way of doing a token refresh silently that does not involve iframes using OIDC-Client-TS? Alternatively, suggestions for alternative libraries capable of achieving silent token renewal without the use of iframes would be greatly appreciated? Thanks